# Multiple fireballs gml

Tags: game-maker

I am programming a bossfight in gamemaker, and I want my boss to shoot multiple fireballs simultaneously, but all in a bit of a different direction, a little bit like this, from rogue soul: [image: rogue soul picture]
It (obviously) doesn't work, and I have been trying for over an hour.
My script is:

```
//in the create event of fireball 1 
direction = hero + 10
speed = 12

//in the create event of fireball 2
direction = hero + 5
speed = 12
```

and so on.

It just refuses to work. The fireballs go a completely random direction, independent of where the hero is.

Comment: Have you been able to shoot _one_ fireball in the direction of the hero?

Comment: It may be happening that from the position of the hero being received from various moments.

Posting an image of what is going on in your game can help.

Without first seeing it, I can recommend one more thing. Start with the first fireball with (hero - 10), second (hero - 5), third (hero), fourth (hero + 5) and fifth (hero +10).

Comment: How do you compute your `hero` direction variable?

Comment: I figured it out myself. Thanks very much for the suggestions. And yes, next time I will put a picture of my game in the question :)

Comment: Consider posting an answer showing what you did to solve your problem.